# need explanation on boost::mpl

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

```
typedef vector<long,float,short,double,float,long,long double> types;
typedef fold<
      types
    , int_<0>
    , if_< is_float<_2>,next<_1>,_1 >
    >::type number_of_floats;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( number_of_floats::value, ==, 4 );
```

I don't understand the way fold works, why int_<0>? why is_float<**_2**> ?

Could someone give me some clues to understand this "function" ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int_<0>` is the starting value of the accumulator used for the fold. Try to use `int_<1>` and see what happens.

The third argument is the operator used to fold the sequence. This needs to be a binary metafunction. `if_< is_float<_2>,next<_1>,_1 >` is turned into a lambda expression with two arguments where _1 and _2 refer to the first and second argument this lambda expression takes.

The predicate `is_float<_2>` returns true if the second argument to `if_` is a `float`. `_2` is a placeholder. Placeholders refer to the n-th argument of the template specialization.

next<_1> simply returns the next value of the current state (e.g. `next<int_<0>> == int_<1>`).

If the predicate returns false we simply return _1 which is the unaltered state.

Try to understand what a fold is first, then try to understand the boost::mpl way of doing it.

A simple exercise is to write a fold that return the length of the vector.

Comment: just a precision about placeholer _2 refer to the n-th arguement of if_ or of fold ?and I think it is of fold....

Comment: @guillaume07: No, it refers to the 2nd argument of `if_`.

Comment: and _1 refers to the first argument of for ??

Comment: No, placeholders turn something in a lambda expression. Thus `if_` takes further arguments. I try to clarify that.